# Determining current in a circuit

Tags: current, circuit-analysis, electricity

[image]

Determine the current passing through R3.

Given:

R1=5Ω

R2=5Ω

R3=10Ω

V1=100V

Is2=5 A

Attempt to solve this :

**Using Mesh current analysis**:
[image]
**Mesh 1**:

-V1+R1(I1-Is2)+R2(I1-I2)=0

100+5(I1-5)+5(I1-I2)=0

10I1-5I2=125

**Mesh 2**:

5(I2-I1)+10(I2-Is2)+5i'=0

i'=I1-Is2

This would give us I2=Is2=5A

Hence I1=15A

The current going through R3 would be equal to I2-Is2=5-5=0A

However this answer doesn't seme logical , I can't imagine that there's no current going through R3 since the current i' should obviously split into R2 and R3.

I'd be grateful if someone could point out any mistakes in my calculations.

Comment: Find the voltage at each end of R3, hence the difference in voltage across R3, hence the Ohm’s-law current. Is that consistent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

If you write the nodal equation for node **V1**,

$$(V_1 - 100)/5 + V_1/5 + (V_1 - 5i)/10 = 0$$

and relation for **i** using ohms law in R1,

$$(100 - V_1)/5 = i$$

On solving you get **V1** = 50V and **i** = 10A

\$ \implies V_2 = 5i = 50V \$

Voltage across R3 = \$V_1 - V_2 = 0\$. So obviously the current thru it is zero too, by ohms law.  You can cross check your calculated answers using ohms law in all resistors.

It is not always necessary that a finite value of current flows through each resistor in a circuit. Current flows thru a resistor only if a potential difference exists between its ends.

Comment: @Raku Correct your mesh eqtn --> V1- R1(I1-Is2)- R2(I1-I2) =0. However your expanded version is correct.